# References on time series analysis

Tags: time-series, excel, reference-request

I am interested in time series analysis. I used to evaluate my data by means of Excel. However, I found that *Mathematica* is a powerful tool that can process different kinds of mathematical operations efficiently. Therefore, can you recommend some references about time series analysis by *Mathematica* to improve my skills and knowledge? That would be better than asking about each single detail every time.

Comment: Just curious, can you describe what kind of time series you want to analyze?

Comment: @Jagra personally, I'm working on coastal discharges and their power spectral density.

Answer (score 5):

You could start looking at the online reference, such as:
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TimeSeries.html
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SignalProcessing.html

Answer (score 5):

I made an example in Mathematica, hope this help.

```
dataSet = Import["/Volumes/USB/sync/Mathematica/Time Series Analysis/AirPassengers.csv", "HeaderLines" -> 1 ,"DateStringFormat" -> {"Year", "-", "Month"}]; 

ts = TimeSeries[dataSet];

testStationarity[ts_] := Module[{ma, sd},
    ma = MovingMap[Mean, ts, Quantity[12, "Months"]]; 
    sd = MovingMap[StandardDeviation, ts, Quantity[12, "Months"]];

    DateListPlot[{ts, ma, sd}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"Original", "Moving Mean", "Moving STD"}]
];

testStationarity[dataSet]
```

[image]